# rails query has many association, how to find out the datas only have one child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

here is the detail:
 model question has many answers.
 so how to find out all questions which only has one answer (question.answers.count == 1).
 anyway to query it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails `Counter Cache` http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column + usual `Question.includes(:answers).where(:answers_count => 1)`
Besides this will later allow you to make less queries to database

Answer (score 0):

Following should do the trick:

```
Question.joins(:answers).select("count(answers_table_name.id) as answer_count, questions_table_name.id").
group("answers_table_name.question_id").having("answer_count=1")
```

Comment: if the relationship between questions and answers is has_and_belongs_to_many. and i need to find out question which only have answer B. my solution is add another query, like : answer_b.questions.where("questions.id in (?)", one_answer_questions). here will be two steps, is it possible to use one statement to query?